# How to deploy MERN webapp in Production not as college project but as freelancing

Tags: node.js, deployment, cloud, devops, mern

I have developed a project in React, NodeJs, and mongodb for my first client.

There will be around 500 visitors per day on the web app.

But I don't know how to deploy it efficiently and in LOW COST.

Right now i am using MongoDB atlas cloud for database. But is this efficient in deployment?

I have watched many videos on YouTube, telling hostinger vps, digitalocean vps and aws cloud hosting, some are suggesting shared hosting.

I am very confused in this and cost is my main constraint.

Help me deploy my webapp in Production in optimized way.

I searched on YouTube but it is very confusing in choosing between anything.
And also cost is my main constraint.